# Overflow in flutter web when user try to zoom in the screen

Tags: flutter, overflow, zooming, flutter-web

I'm creating a web app using flutter and I've encountered this problem:
when I try to zoom in using the shortcuts (ctrl and +), the widget start to response until they become overflowed and yellow banners start to appear.

how to fix this problem

Comment: could you post your code? screenshot as well? Is hard to tell without anything to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a SingleChildScrollView:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
         padding:
          const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 10),
           child: Text('Login',
            style: TextStyle(
             fontSize: browser* 4,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
               ),
```

[image: Login Page with SCSV]